# Getting links to work correctly in PHP admin/member website

Tags: php, mysql, function, hyperlink

I am working on a PHP/MySQL database driven website and I'm trying to get all the links to work. Just as an example, I'm using ../admin/index.php for the admin pages and ../member/index.php for the member pages in my links. For some reason, when I login a user with a session it doesn't always go to the member pages or admin pages but stays on the regular user pages. If anyone has experience with this sort of thing, I would really appreciate your input.

Some of the code looks like this:

```
 <ul>
 <li class="home"><a href="../member/home.php">Home</a></li>
 <li class="home"><a href="../member/history.php">History</a></li>
 <li class="home"><a href="../member/services.php">Services</a></li>
 <li class="home"><a href="../member/contact.php">Contact</a></li>
 <li class="home"><a href="../member/registration.php">Register?</a></li>
</ul>
```

AND here is a error I get when I click on the home after I've logged in - also, when I've logged in, not all the links show me as logged in and this is the error I'm getting on the home page:

```
Welcome,

 Notice: Undefined variable: level in J:\XAMPP\htdocs\tires\member\home.php     on line 34
,

Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_name() in      J:\XAMPP\htdocs\tires\member\home.php on line 35
```

The fatal error in this - when I use the same function on the regular user pages it is working great.

This is the line 34 and 35 - the entire Function:

```
 <?php

                      //if(isset($results)){
                      if ((isset($_SESSION['loginName'])) === (isset($results['email']))) {
               echo "Welcome, <br />";
               echo "$level, <br />";
               echo get_name($results); 
              // print_r($_POST);
               print '<br />';}
               else{
            var_dump($results);
          }
```

And, this is the get_name($results) function:

```
function get_name($results) {
$name = preg_split("/@/", $results['email']);
$name = ucfirst($name[0]);
 return $name;
                            };
```

Comment: Not enough information to help you. Post your PHP code.

Comment: post your line 34 and 35 of home.php

Comment: @Halfstop, I posted more code. I hope this helps.

Comment: @Adrean Cid Almaguer, I posted the lines you requested. I hope you can help me and thank you both so much for trying. God bless you both.